# how to make a session persistent with .net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, cookies

Is there a way to set a persistent session that would not expire when closing/re-opening a browser. The cookie that is used to store the session_id expires when the browser is closed.

I know we can make the Auth persistent (stay logged in when we close and re-open a browser). In this case, the cookie does NOT expire when the browser is closed

Hope this make sense :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not just tie information to a user and store it in the DB or to a file on the server instead?  Or, Cache shouldn't expire too...

HTH.